# How to listen to all socket events from a feathersjs server

Tags: socket.io, feathersjs

Does anyone know of a socket firehose in feathers? ie: `socket.on('all'...)` or a specific event that feathers produces for all socket messges?

Answer (score 0):

Not by default. But you could do something like

```js
app.mixins.push(function(service) {
  service._serviceEvents.forEach(event, data => {
    service.emit('all', { data, event });
  });
});
```

Which will emit an `all` even with `{ data, even }` additionally to all service events

---

thx @daffl